# Get the id using value or label text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<label class="" for="option1">
  <input title="Select All" type="checkbox" id="option1" value="Select All" />
  Select All
</label>
```

Now I want to get the id of input using value or label text="Select All" by using Jquery.
Help me sort out Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please update your question to include the HTML structure you're asking about, and to say more clearly what event or condition it is that makes you want to make something happen, and what it is you want that something to be. I suggest reading Jon Skeet's [*Writing the Perfect Question*](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)...

Comment: ...or at least his [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attribute selector `$('[title="Select All]"]')`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var id = $('[title="Select All"]').attr('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="" for="option1">
<input title="Select All" type="checkbox" id="option1" value="Select All" />
Select All
</label>
```